# Filtro middleware laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Soy nuevo en Laravel y estoy trabajando en una practica en la que me gustaria que el usuario si no cumple con cierta informacion no pueda acceder a otras url's, especificamente si no completo un formulario, por lo que lei se podria utilizar un middleware como filtro pero desconozco como hacerlo funcionar.

En la base de datos hay una tabla con una columna llamada perfilID que tiene el id del usuario que envio el formulario y otra llamada IsNew en la cual se inserta un "1" si el usuario completo su formulario o es Null si nunca lo ha hecho,

en mi archivo de rutas lo especifique asi

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('IsNew')->name('home');
```

y el codigo del middleware quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use DB;
use User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsNew
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $perfilID = Auth::user()->id;
        $IsNew = DB::table('perfils')->pluck('IsNew')->Where('perfilID', $perfilID)->first();
        if ($IsNew = 1) {
            return redirect('admin/perfil');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero este no funciona, les repito soy nuevo con los middleware e hice este codigo con lo poco que encontre en internet, espero puedan orientarme a filtrar si en la tabla perfils no exite NINGUN registro con el id del usuario lo redireccione al formulario (admin/perfil) y si hay un registro que contega el id del usuario continue normal al siguiente paso

Answer (score 0):

Como primer medida, deberías especificar cual es el error que obtienes, o que obtienes en vez de lo esperado. Ya que eres nuevo en laravel, te recomiendo que si le pusiste un nombre a tu ruta, lo utilices. Ejemplo:

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

Y creo que la razón de que tu middleware funciona de manera incorrecta es porque estas haciendo mal la comparación en:

```
  if ($IsNew = 1) {
```

Debería ser:

```
  if ($IsNew == 1) {
        return redirect('admin/perfil');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comenta como te fue, suerte!